# How to split a data set with duplicated informations based on date

Tags: r, duplicates, na

I have this situation:

```
ID   date          Weight
1   2014-12-02       23
1   2014-10-02       25
2   2014-11-03       27
2   2014-09-03       45
3   2014-07-11       56
3      NA            34
4   2014-10-05       25
4   2014-08-09       14
5      NA            NA
5      NA            NA
```

And I would like split the dataset in this, like this:

1-

```
ID   date          Weight
1   2014-12-02       23
1   2014-10-02       25
2   2014-11-03       27
2   2014-09-03       45
4   2014-10-05       25
4   2014-08-09       14
```

2- Lowest Date

```
  ID   date          Weight
    3   2014-07-11       56
    3      NA            34
    5      NA            NA
    5      NA            NA
```

I tried this for second dataset:

```
dt <- dt[order(dt$ID, dt$date), ]
dt.2=dt[duplicated(dt$ID), ]
```

but didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the `ID`'s for which `date` are `NA` and then `subset` based on that

```
NA_ids <- unique(df$ID[is.na(df$date)])
subset(df, !ID %in% NA_ids)

#  ID       date Weight
#1  1 2014-12-02     23
#2  1 2014-10-02     25
#3  2 2014-11-03     27
#4  2 2014-09-03     45
#7  4 2014-10-05     25
#8  4 2014-08-09     14

subset(df, ID %in% NA_ids)

#   ID       date Weight
#5   3 2014-07-11     56
#6   3       <NA>     34
#9   5       <NA>     NA
#10  5       <NA>     NA
```

---

Using `dplyr`, we can create a new column which has `TRUE`/`FALSE` for each `ID` based on presence of `NA` and then use `group_split` to split into list of two.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
 group_by(ID) %>%
 mutate(NA_ID = any(is.na(date))) %>%
 ungroup %>%
 group_split(NA_ID, keep = FALSE)
```

The above `dplyr` logic can also be implemented in base R by using `ave` and `split`

```
df$NA_ID <- with(df, ave(is.na(date), ID, FUN = any))
split(df[-4], df$NA_ID)
```